# Filemaker Update Container field with image?

Tags: odbc, filemaker

I am trying to save an image to a filemaker table container field to no avail. I make a service call which returns a image token. and then i do another call to another service passing the token to get image. now i am trying to save that image back to the record with the specific token.

```
   static void WriteImageRecord(string token, Image image)
        {
            lock (_object)
            {
                string update_query ="UPDATE ImageTable SET PutAs('DDImageByteString','PNGf')=? WHERE \"DDImageToken\"="+"'"+token+"'";

                OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(update_query);
                connOpen();
                if (connData.State == ConnectionState.Broken || connData.State == ConnectionState.Closed) { connOpen(); } else { }

                if (image != null)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", OdbcType.Image).Value = image;
                }
                cmd.Connection = connData;
                try {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logWriteLine(update_query);
                    logWriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + ": " + ex.Message);
                }
                connClose();
            }
        }
```

Here is my command text:

"UPDATE ImageTable SET PutAs('DDImageByteString','PNGf')=? WHERE \"DDImageToken\"='NlxRM0NYBlNvRVYTCGtbTy8TQBIAXH9bAENsWFQpVBtOdVxTbCk6LVVzRlVcRTMdXmRZUHBCVkVcc0JRQ0MRFRJ0WVBhQVhaXnpFXE9WcA=='"

Error received: "No mapping exists from object type System.Drawing.Bitmap to a known managed provider native type." and I am unsure how to resolve.

Comment: Are you sure you are using PNGf as the type?

Comment: It is also a bug in FileMaker ODBC which was around for a bit